# Use git to merge sites that aren't already under version control

Tags: git, diff

We have a website at work which we keep two copies of - one is the live site, or master copy and the other is a test / staging site where big changes are made and tested before copying them over - manually at the moment - to the live site and published.

We've just finished a checkout overhaul on the site which has led to the creation or modification of about 40 files.

#### My question is this:

can we create two git branches, one for each site, and then use git to generate a list of differences and merge the test changes into the live site, even though the site isn't CURRENTLY under version control?

Comment: How about you first place the site(s) under version control and then apply the changes?

Comment: Why not directly work with git? ;) Then you have no problems and you can merge it.

Comment: I have gave you few options to do it with git. feel free to ask in detailed to get more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by initializing a git repo for your website.

```
cd prod_site
git init
git add -A #You may want to ignore some files like libraries for example, use a .gitignore
git commit -m "Initial prod commit"
```

Now that your prod site is under version control, create a branch then copy your staging website on it.

```
git checkout -b staging
cp -r /path/to/staging/website .
git commit -am "Staging website"
```

Now you have two branches:

- `master` with your prod website
- `staging` with your staging website

Now you can list differences between your two branches with a `git diff`

```
git diff master..staging
```

Comment: Hi, this was how I ended up doing it, so I have accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

You have several options:
But why not using [beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) for example?

---

## Using branches

```
# cd to the desired folder
# place the content of the first branch in the folder

# init the folder as git repository
git init

# add all the files in the directory and commit them to stash
git add . -A
git commit 

# create a new branch for the second content
git checkout -b <b2>

# now copy the second content to this folder

# add the content of the second branch to git
git add . -A

# commit the changes
git commit
```

## Viewing view the diff

The simple way is to use git status before you are adding the content of the second branch to git

Before you do this form the previous step:

#### git status

```
# now copy the second content to this folder
git add . -A
git commit 

# display the differences between the branches
git status
```

or 
    # show the differences between the current HEAD and the content waiting 
    # to be committed
    git add . 
    git diff

[image]

#### View changes

You can view the differences between the branch sin many ways

```
git log --cc
git log master ^b1
git log ^master b1     
gir format-patch HEAD~1
```

and more...